# JavaFx TextField Listener

Tags: java, javafx

Не совсем понятно как работать с слушателем TextField , куда конкретно писать метод, нужно ли помечать в FXML файле метод в onAction. Буду рад ссылочке, нормальной инфы не нашёл.
В кратце, у меня есть метод, который должен не давать вводить любые символы, кроме цифр, но по итогу ничего не работает

```
@FXML
    void posCount2(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d*)?");
    secondCount.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!p.matcher(newValue).matches()) secondCount.setText(oldValue);
    });
    }
```

Comment: Помещаете там же где находятся поля, к которым обращаетесь в методе. Помечать как @FXML не нужно. Добавление листенера к текстовому полю делаете в init.

Comment: @insolor благодарю